# Trying to upload a file in laravel but it doesn't seem to exist

Tags: php, html, laravel-5

Hi I'm new to laravel and was trying to upload a .csv file.

My code looks like this:

**CLIENT_SIDE (BLADE)**

```
 <form role='form' action="{{route('webscrape.upload')}}" method ="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-parsley-validate="">

   {{ csrf_field() }}

   <input type='file' name="data" required="">
   <br>
   <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Import' class="btn btn-info btn-lg" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit these information?')">
 </form>
```

**SERVER_SIDE (CONTROLLER)**

```
public function uploadFile(Request $request){

    if ($request->input('submit') != null ){
       $file = $request->file('data');
       if (file_exists('data')) {
         dd('hello');
       } else {
        dd('hi');
      }
    }
}
```

I keep getting hi even when I upload a file. I already checked the routes to make sure the names and links are fine. Any advice would be great. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

From what i perceive, you are using `file_exists()` to check a string instead of the actual file path and in this case it will never work.

My advice for you:

You should pass the actual path of the file that you want to check for. In order to do that, you can write something like this:

```
$file = $request->file('data');
$path = $file->getPathname();
if (file_exists($path)) {
   echo 'hello';
} else {
   echo 'hi';
}
```